# Trying to implement a controller file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So, I'm trying to make some kinda instagram clone... just for practice in MERN stack.
I'm actually following up a tutorial. The problem is that the tutorial teachs to make almost everything in the server.js . Since I don't think It's clean and organized I tried to make some changes in my code. First I created a routes.js file. Then I created a model with the mongoose.Schema({}) to create my object.
The problem here is that I want to implement a controller file to make the routes.js even cleaner.
My controller's code:

```
const Post = mongoose.model("Posts");

export default function store(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;

  Post.create(body, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }
  });
}
```

The Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
at Route. [as post]

My routes's code:

```
import express from "express";
import PostController from "./controllers/PostController.js";
const routes = express.Router();
routes.post("/upload", PostController.store);
```

My models's code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  caption: String,
  user: String,
  image: String,
  comments: [],
});

export default mongoose.model("Posts", PostSchema);
```

I'm sorry for the big post. But I hope someone could help meu out =)
Oh, other question... Is there a better way to make It more organized? I actually have no idea if that is a great option. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Try using `module.exports` instead of the new `export default` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you try to access a property called `store` on the thing you import.

Note that you export the post controller using `export default function`. That means when you import it, the import *itself* will be that function. You won't get an object with a property called `store`. Your `store` function *is* the post controller.

When you write `PostController.store`, you're basically trying to access a property called `store` on your post controller function. But that function has no such property. It *is* that property you're looking for.

Try doing the following instead:

```js
routes.post("/upload", PostController);
```

Comment: Hey @weltschmerz, thanks for your answer! It worked fine! But I have one more doubt. How can I export other requests in the same file? My first idea was to make all the Post's request in the PostController. That's why I tried to use PostController.method. For exalmple:
routes.post("/upload", PostController.store);
routes.get("/upload", PostController.index);
...
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I can't test it right now, but try removing the "default" from the export statement, and then export each function individually. so `export function store() { ... }` then, on the next line, `export function index() { ... }` and so on. Let me know if that doesn't work.